# Why is Amazon SES DKIM signature marked as perm_fail?

Tags: amazon-web-services, email, amazon-ses, dkim

I am trying to send an email via Amazon SES. I came across a pretty weird behaviour regarding the email's DKIM Signature.

According to [this documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/dg/troubleshoot-dkim.html), the last 2 lines stipulate that Amazon SES adds a DKIM signature of its own, which looks like this:

```
Received-SPF: pass (domain of amazonses.com designates 5.240.8.29 as permitted sender)
Authentication-Results: atlas222.free.mail.bf1.yahoo.com;
 dkim=perm_fail header.i=@amazonses.com header.s=6gbrjpgwjskckoa6a5zn6fwqkn67xbtw;
 spf=pass smtp.mailfrom=amazonses.com;
 dmarc=unknown header.from=somedomain.com;
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; q=dns/txt; c=relaxed/simple;
    s=6gbrjpgwjskckoa6a5zn6fwqkn67xbtw; d=amazonses.com; t=167098234;
    h=Date:MIME-Version:Message-ID:To:From:Reply-To:Subject:Feedback-ID:List-Unsubscribe:List-Unsubscribe-Post:List-Help:Content-Transfer-Encoding:Content-Type;
    bh=N9guynJNBoGOSIx//oL1JHgbJyamt5u5yxgWxtw04xA=;
    b=geaU3laohsTcVBHSolTgZ2v9L9QKv0dD7B9UIpuPWIEnaUS2COUXFHrlTR66dN7p
    j7D90DpKM4hUYUU2LGUIBWw6xGv/4clqol45DBYNZnvyTD9TRR+D3PL6AH2oezRggV1
    MTnZ2ygtXlSctbJKWDeZR1AUlAw5VJJrFea9LxQE=
```

If I activate my DKIM on SES, another signature is added as well as another DKIM line `dkim=perm_fail header.i=@amazonses.com...`. and when correctly set-up it has `pass` status.

How can a DKIM signature added by Amazon SES have `perm_fail` status? Is there a way to correct that?

Comment: "Another DKIM signature is added" - does it mean you have several dkim signatures? DId you forwarded any emails etc? Can you provide the headers with another mail after you activate dkim?

Comment: Well, All DKIM Process is managed in SES. the DKIM header in the question is present in ALL mails going through SES. (Regardless whether I add a DKIM or not) now if I tell SES to add DKIM using my domain XXXX.com for ex, SES will add another DKIM-Signature header in the email headers (d=XXXX.com this time). and I will have 2 signatures. and in the Authentication-Results added by yahoo you see dkim=perm_fail header.i=@amazonses.com header.s=6gbrjpgwjskckoa6a5zn6fwqkn67xbtw; And dkim=perm_fail header.i=@XXXX.com header.s=6gbrjpgwjskckoa6a5zn6fwqkn67xbtw;

Comment: Since Comment can't hold too much characters, if you want If it's not clean enough I can upload a txt file somewhere with full headers

Comment: Is the domain managed by AWS? If you can provide the full headers in the question it would make it much easier in the debug. What can i say from the start is to go to mxtoolbox and verify that all the dkim keys are available

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally ! After hours and hours of searching and testing I found out why the Amazon SES DKIM check fails.

It was an encoding problem.

Sending e-mails with the utf8 allowed mime type will cause this error when some exotic characters are sent in email body/headers.

When sending a simple email with a hello world body the DKIM was pass. but sending an email containing a character like this one `ᥱ` for example with the utf8 led DKIM to fail.

Comment: Did you only run into this issue for Outlook receivers? I'm getting extremely odd DKIM failures, but it appears to only impact Outlook inboxes, not Google/Gmail inboxes.